# Смена папка (chdir)

Tags: c, cd

есть такой код:

```
char *args[10];

char split(char *commadnForSpilt) { //FIX to strtok
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (commadnForSpilt, " ");
    char *array[3];

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char line[350];
int max = 150;
fgets(line,max, stdin);

split(line);

if((strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0)) {
    chdir(args[1]);
}

}
```

Но когда запускаю и ввожу

> "cd .."

Появляется ошибка:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

Где ошибка?

Пишу свой микрошел(для практики)

Comment: Запустите пошагово и посмотрите что в массиве

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос вызван невнимательностью и ленью, и не принесет пользы будущим посетителям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок действительно достаточно, но в целом подход нормальный. Больше читайте теорию и решайте задачи для понимания работы кода и памяти, смотрите примеры, благо сейчас в интернете тонны разнообразной полезной информации. Вот немного доработанный код с пояснениями:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/// Замена символов в строке. Пригодится позже.
int replacechar(char *str, char orig, char rep) {
    char *ix = str;
    int n = 0;
    while((ix = strchr(ix, orig)) != NULL) {
        *ix++ = rep;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

/// Принимает на вход массив и возвращает число элементов в нём
/// Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что `strtok` не выделяет новую память,
/// а только редактирует данную строку и указывает на её части.
size_t split(char *commadnForSpilt, char** array) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (commadnForSpilt, " ");
    while (p != NULL) {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /// Текущая директория
    char cwd[256];
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)); printf("cwd: %s\n", cwd);

    /// Введённая команда
    char command[256];

    // fgets(command, 255, stdin);
    /// Для теста можно и так:
    sprintf(command, "cd ..\n");

    /// После fgets в конце строки будет знак переноса, его стоит убрать:
    replacechar(command, '\n', ' ');
    /// Можно заменить и на \0, смотрите сами

    /// Разбиваем строку на части. Во имя инкапсуляции массив лучше
    /// объявлять здесь и передавать в функцию
    char *args[10];
    size_t count = split(command, args);

    /// Вывод токенов команды
    printf("Got tokens:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\t%s\n", args[i]);
    }

    /// Обрабатываем команды
    if ((strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0)) {
        chdir("..");
    }

    /// Новая текущая директория
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)); printf("cwd: %s\n", cwd);
}
```

Дальше можно обернуть этот код в цикл для постоянного ввода команд, накидывать разные типы команд и т.п.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

А что вы вообще делаете?

В `split` пишете строки (кстати, вместо `".."` вы получите `"..\n"`) в какой-то массив `array`, о котором тут же при выходе из функции забываете (кстати, где возврат обещанного `char` из `split`?), и пытаетесь работать с `args`, в котором, как в глобальной переменной, лежат одни нулевые указатели...

P.S. Нервным далее не читать

Ну хоть чуть-чуть быть внимательнее? Ну откуда такое стремление - не думая, писать сюда и спрашивать? Еще и позориться - такими глупыми ошибками...

Это именно то, что я безуспешно пытаюсь донести до масс [на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10036/195342)...

Comment: Ну так я только учусь, как я могу знать все прямо сейчас
Но спасибо за ответ,

Comment: При чем тут "учусь"? Если вы пишете `a = 5`, то вас потом не удивляет, что `b` не равно 5? Если вы кладете, ну, не знаю... носки в верхний ящик комода, а потом лезете в нижний - а их там нет - вам приходится высовываться с балкона и спрашивать у прохожих, почему вы не можете найти носки? А это - **одно и то же**!!! Или вы внушили себе, что программирование - это очень сложно (тогда зачем вы за него взялись?), или вам просто лень.